# Terraform mongodbatlas disk size scale down unexpected

Tags: terraform, mongodb-atlas

I have `backend "remote"` configured with provider `mongodb/mongodbatlas`. Mongodb Atlas cluster configured with `auto_scaling_disk_gb_enabled = true`. Also during first deploy there was specified `disk_size_gb = 15`. Since auto scaling is enabled in a while cluster changed size to bigger one `21Gb`. Next application of terraform script via `app.terraform.io` showed plan for this cluster which included `disk_size_gb : 21 change to 15`. Terraform version used: `1.1.7`
Since I'm quite new to terraform it's not clear for me if this is expected behavior to attempt scaling down disk size? I see specifically this step took lots of time (maybe 40 minutes), however completed successfully. Is this possible to not perform scaling down disk size and leave there `disk_size_gb` specified?